# Extremely high gas fees

Tags: gas-price

I'm paying 0.38 gas fees in this function. There's something wrong with it?

```
function claim() external {
    require(allowed[msg.sender] == true, 'This address is not allowed to perform withdrawns');
    require(BUSD.balanceOf(address(this)) > block.timestamp - moment[msg.sender] * allowance[msg.sender], 'Not enough balance');
    uint amount = moment[msg.sender] * allowance[msg.sender];
    BUSD.transferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, amount);
    allowance[msg.sender] = 0;
    emit claimed(msg.sender, amount);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVM gives such high fees when function is supposed to fail. In this case the culprit is `transferFrom()`. I don't think you should to use `BUSD.transferFrom()` here. You want to send msg.sender the amount calculated from the contract's address. Since contract will be the BUSD contract caller in this case, you should use:

```
BUSD.transfer(msg.sender, amount);
```